# Duplicate data in my tableview while using endless scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm using this method to implement endless scrolling in my tableview:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView_
{
CGFloat actualPosition = scrollView_.contentOffset.y ;
CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView_.contentSize.height - (700);
NSLog(@"table: %f", self.tableView.frame.size.height);
if (actualPosition >= contentHeight)
{  // self.articles = NULL;
    [self makeRequest:currentpage++];
    [self.articlesArray addObjectsFromArray:articles];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
}
```

I fetch data from a web service like so:

```
-(void)makeRequest:(int)page1{


NSString *urlString = [NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"http://url/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=%d",(int) page1];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSData *theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];

self.articles = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:nil];

}
```

In my view controller's viewDidLoad is the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.articlesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 self.articles = [[NSMutableArray array]init];
currentpage = 0;
}
```

I get the data twice before the new data is shown. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

When making paging requests like this, simply keep track of if a request is in progress. In your file's interface keep track of a variable such as:

```
bool isLoadingMoreData = NO
```

then, when yo make a request:

```
-(void)makeRequest:(int)page1{

if (self.isLoadingMoreData) {
    return
}
self.isLoadingMoreData = YES

NSString *urlString = [NSString
                       stringWithFormat:@"http://url/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=%d",(int) page1];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSData *theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];

self.articles = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:nil];

self.isLoadingMoreData = NO

}
```

This is a simple way to keep you from making duplicated requests